# Running two git commands in parallel

Tags: git, parallelism, multiuser

What happens if two `git pull` command are run simultaneously in the same directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git` does file locking to prevent corrupting the repository.  You may get messages like

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/develop': is at 2cfbc5fed0c5d461740708db3f0e21e5a81b87f9 but expected 36c438af7c374e5d131240f9817dabb27d2e0a2c
From github.com:myrepository
 ! 36c438a..2cfbc5f  develop    -> origin/develop  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': is at b9a3f6cf9dafc30df38542e5e51ae4842c50814d but expected 5e6174b3c7071c840effeda6c708d6aef36f7c6a
 ! 5e6174b..b9a3f6c  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
```

from the `git` processes that fail to get the lock. That is all.

If the two `git pull` processes are slightly out of sync with each other, the effect will be the same as running the command twice.